# Web development tool that can comprehend the concept of more than one language in a file at once

Tags: php, javascript, html, ide

I currently use notepad++ on windows or gedit on ubuntu. Both of them work great with code highlighting and hinting etc. But both of them suffer from a huge flaw. I am yet to find a code editor that can handle this concept:

```
<?php
// ooh, look I am doing some php
?><a onclick="alert('hay, some javascript in here now!')">
This link is HTML?!</a>
<?PHP
echo("NOW we have some php as well!");
?>
```

At the moment, I just have to settle for the one language. I want something that can think of a that text as a default as HTML, but notice when sections are PHP. I want those sections of PHP to have there own code hinting and highlighting. Even more, lets say in an 'if else' I exit PHP, write some HTML then back into PHP, I want it to work out how the braces ( '{' and '}' ) should match up and let me know if I have missed one. I want the sections of in-line JavaScript to be picked up as such. I want all of these languages to get checked for syntax!

Damn it, I want to tool that understands more than one language at once!

**Extra**

Should point out that I am not willing to pay for such luxury :P

My files are saved as '.php'.

Notepad++ is able to to work out that I am using PHP but when I drop out of php and do some HTML and/or some JavaScript.

Comment: What file extension are you using?

Comment: Not sure why this is happening to you. I am using notepad++ and it can discern between php and html :-? (I mean I pasted your code and it worked fine. npp 5.6.8 default styles)

Comment: Dreamweaver CS5 can do that for you (the PHP codehinting support in CS5 is much better than CS4) - but it's not free :)

Comment: Note that what you're asking for is not quite as trivial as you may think :), e.g. inside an "echo" statement  in PHP you are technically speaking inside the PHP section (in a string), but nevertheless it's conceivable that you may still want/expect HTML tag hinting and even javascript hinting
Furthermore, imagine in a JS section you have a PHP sub-section that emits part of the JS code... how do you continue hinting for JS? there's no way to tell what code will be emitted in PHP.
There are plenty of scenarios that may break the hinting when you mix the languages a lot.

Comment: @Virgil I realise this is no simple task. But I think some things can be done to help simplify. eg echo shouldn't be used to echo html, for that you should drop out of PHP, echo should be used just for echoing variables. the `onclick` attributes, these should always(?) be passed as JavaScript. And if you do have a PHP section in JavaScript, then only that section should be treated as PHP, the JavaScript parser should skip over the PHP part.

Comment: If only it were so simple :)
The biggest problem I think is PHP in javascript - e.g. to initialize JSon objects. Yes, you can attempt to skip PHP, but then the error recovery is non-trivial at best :) (would you like to have syntax errors flaged in your file just because you mixed PHP and JS? Yup, I didn't think so either :) ).
[edit]to be clear: if you simply pretend (for the JS parser) that "the PHP code will emit nothing", the probability that you'll end up with a syntax error gets close to 100%. You can hide the error, but often you're in the wrong state too...recovering state is harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) or [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s based on Eclipse like [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) or [Zend Studio](http://zend.com/products/studio).
Or try [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/). Should all be able to do what you want.

In case you cannot decide which to use, see the various Q&A's on that topic

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=which+IDE+php

Answer (score 3):

[PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/index.html) is probably the most powerful IDE for your requirements. Pricey, but give it a go. I think it's worth it...

Comment: Probably should of said in question, but I am not willing to pay for such a luxury either :P

Comment: It's free for 45 days. tryyyyyy iiiiiiiiit

Comment: They just announced until mid-September you can buy a personal or small-biz version for $49, $99 after that. It will be well worth the money....the beta is FANTASTIC and will do what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), with the [nxhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) mode.

Answer (score 1):

`gedit`, being based on `gtksourceview`, absolutely does support nested language blocks. If I save your example as `.php`, I get syntax highlighting for both PHP and HTML.

And indeed for JavaScript in `<script>` blocks, though not inline event handler attributes. (Which would be tricky because those aren't CDATA, they're HTML: the syntax highlighter would have to know what `if (a&amp;&amp;b)` represented. Anyway, you don't want to be using event handler attributes.)